# nested for loop function

Tags: python, function, loops

I would like to create a nested function that iterates two loops for 2 lists of parameters to plot them.

```
distance = ['euclidean', 'l1', 'l2', 'manhattan', 'cosine']
links = ['complete', 'average', 'single']

for distance in distance:
    for links in links:
        agglomerative_fun(2, distance, links)
```

is this the correct way to do it? When I put it each at a time the function works, but when I iterate it gives me an error.

Comment: What is the error? Also, both your iteration variables and your lists are named the same (`distance` and `links`). This will most likely cause problems

Comment: You want `for link in links`, not `for links in links`, and then use `link` in your call.

Comment: ah ok got. it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming the iterator object in the for loop is important, so make sure you're not using the same name for the array you are iterating. Here's a tip: using a short word like "link" or a single letter like "l" is best practice for writing for loops.

```
distance = ['euclidean', 'l1', 'l2', 'manhattan', 'cosine']
links = ['complete', 'average', 'single']

for distance in distance:
    for l in links:
        agglomerative_fun(2, distance, l)
```